# Run terminal with commands after startup on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: boot, terminal

I need to open the terminal on startup and execute three commands in the same window automatically on my Raspberry 4B. The first is a cd command. The second one is: source /tflite/bin/activate. And the last one is: python program.py. After executing the last one, I need to keep the program running. I've tried solutions from similar threads like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507243/start-shell-script-on-raspberry-pi-startup) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641120/running-terminal-and-entering-commands-on-startup-raspberry-pi) but none of them worked for me. I also tried making an sh file, which executed the commands separately and had some other issues (The python program was executed and was running in a loop (which was intended) but when it got a point when it had to run another program it did nothing although it normally works.). I've also modified the ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file, but it didn't work.

Comment: `this or this` you failed to actually link to anything

Comment: `had some other issues` ... please describe the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is you want to run those command *in a terminal*.  Put them in a script and then execute them from the LXDE autostart this way:

```
lxterminal -e /path/to/script
```

Note that this terminal will close when the script finishes, which should be okay if it starts a python program that loops.  Otherwise, add `bash` to the end of the script to keep the terminal open.

It seems there are some caveats about using the per-user autostart file you should be aware of: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=294014

For more details about using the terminal see `man lxterminal`.